# Get Unique Identity Of Pc(system) Using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, unique, identity

I am developing a JavaScript application and I need a piece of code that can identify the PC LAN IP because I want to prevent unauthorized user to access my application and main factor is PC is not connected to internet but only connected to static LAN IP so how can I achieve this?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you seriously ask for a __pic of code__?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get Client IP using just Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/391979/get-client-ip-using-just-javascript)

Comment: You would normally protect your application at the server, as you have no control over modifications to your client app.

Answer (score 0):

```
function myIP(){ var vi="uses java to get the users local ip number"
    var yip2=java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost();   
    var yip=yip2.getHostAddress();
  return yip;
}//end myIP

alert("your machine's local network IP is "+ myIP());
```

Reference : http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?242538-Getting-local-IP-address-in-javascript